# Errors when uploading archive to app store

Tags: xcode, cordova, app-store

I am trying to upload my archive to the app store and I am getting the following errors.

[image]

I'm not sure how I'm getting these? I never set a description and can't find it in xcode. I am using the latest Cordova and I do have images (it all worked fine for Play store).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the following:

1) Your images are exactly of the dimensions it is complaining:

- 120 x 120
- 152 x 152
- 1024 x 1024

Open those images in a tool like Sketch or Photoshop and ensure it is correct. I have faced similar issues when the dimension is off by half a pixel. if it is 120 x 119.5, in finder it'll show as 120 x 120. Check the dimensions for every image.

2) If your app icon is being loaded from the image assets, check the image asset and ensure the respective icon images are loaded correctly.

3) The marketing icon and the description can be updated on iTunes connect. Make sure you have updated these when you set your app for Prepare for Submission on iTunes Connect. Without a description for your app, it'll not accept a submission.

Comment: Thanks they are those dimensions. Why does complain about description? I set a description in Connect but not the app.

Comment: I found an image that was 1px off, once I fixed that the description went away too.

Comment: glad it helped! was it one of the 3 images it was complaining?

Comment: Yes, one image was off by 1px.